# Rails map two fields in form to one field in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am using Rails 4.2rc3 and the `simple_form` gem.

I have an `Event` model which has a field `reservations_open_at` which indicates how many seconds before the event starts that reservations can start to be made (e.g. reservations might open up 2 days in advance, or maybe 10 hours in advance).

However, I want to use a form with a text input for a number (`reservations_open_at_amount`) and a select form for either 'Hours' or 'Days' (`reservations_open_at_unit`). I.e. the user can input '2 days' or '10 hours' via the two fields.

I can't quite figure out the right way to use virtual attributes to set the `reservations_open_at` field in seconds using a regular `@event.update(event_params)` call in my controller.

I don't need to remember whether the user chose Hours or Days when editing an existing record; if the `reservations_open_at` amount modulo (24*60*60) is zero (i.e. the number of seconds is an exact multiple of days) then I will display the form with `reservations_open_at / (24*60*60)` and `Days`, else `reservations_open_at / (60*60)` and `Hours`.

Answer (score 1):

You are already more than half way there.

In the model, add two virtual attributes, time_amount, time_units. Add these 2 to the views.
Add a before_save callback to set the value in reservations_open_at.

Something like:

**Edit:** add getter for time unit

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :time_unit, time_amount
  before_save :calculate_open_at
  ...
  def time_unit
    return @time_unit if @time_unit

    if ( self.time_amount = reservations_open_at / 1.day.seconds ) > 0
      @time_unit = 'days'
    else
      self.time_amount = reservations_open_at / 1.hour.seconds
      @time_unit = 'hours'
    end
  end

  def calculate_open_at
    conversion_rate = time_unit == "days" ? 1.day.seconds : 1.hour.seconds
    self.reservations_open_at = time_amount * conversion_rate
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: This works fine when viewing a form with a new object. However, if you are editing an existing object then the form fields will be blank.

Creating methods such as
`def time_unit` `(reservations_open_at % 1.day.seconds == 0) ? "days" : "hours"` `end`

causes the code to break.

Comment: Use the `@time_unit` instance variable directly and check if it has already been set.  The `time_amount` assignment above may not be appropriate.